# SSRS Query driven Parameter Subscription - Available Values Changing

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have created a report that uses a multi-value parameter. This parameter gets it's available values from a query.

The data for my report is a list of stock. The available values for my parameter are distinct Customers from this list.

This all works fine.

The available values of customers is a subset of the entire list of customers. That is intended, we are holding stock for ~100 customers and there are ~500 customers total.

## 1 - What would happen if a subscription was created, with customer "JoeBloggs" as the parameter, and there was no longer any stock for this customer, and thus it was no longer an available value? What if there are multiple parameters, some have stock and some don't?

## 2 - Assuming #1 is not an issue, is there a way I would be able to create subscriptions with parameters that are not currently available from the query?

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question, the subscription will fail if the parameter value is not available.
But I don't think this is a Problem. If you have 100 customers, you will create a data driven subscription anyways. then you can just make the view behind the subscription so that it has only customers with stock.